# Graphicsmagick package error

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use the cfs:graphicsmagick package to generate thumbnails but all that is generated is an empty image.

When I start the server things look good:

```
I20150108-10:43:14.698(-8)? => GraphicsMagick found
I20150108-10:43:14.901(-8)? available
=> Meteor server restarted
```

but it seems gm is not available:

```
if (gm.isAvailable) {
    console.log("gm is available");
}
```

and the console throws out an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [docs](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-graphicsmagick/blob/master/tests/server-tests.js), seems like the gm scope its just available on the server side, so there is not problem here, you are having the console.log, pretty find

now you can use, on the fsCollection like this

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [
  new FS.Store.FileSystem("images"),
  new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {
    transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
      // Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
      gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10', '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
    }
  })
],
filter: {
  allow: {
    contentTypes: ['image/*'] //allow only images in this FS.Collection
  }
}
});
```

remember  `gm` its just available on the server, so use it on `/server` or use on `if(isServer)`

Try this

```
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
       if (gm.isAvailable) {
        console.log("gm is available and this console.log was printed from my own code");
      }
    }
```

Tell me if works

**Update answer**

If you are declaring FS.collection on both server/client i recommend you declare collection on `/lib/collection.js` like this

```
      //collections.js
      Adopcion = new FS.Collection("Adopcion", {
stores: [
  new FS.Store.FileSystem("images"),
  new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {
    transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
      // Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
      gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10', '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
    }
  })
]
});
```

and on the same file make the subscription
     //collection.js
    //Subscribe
    if(Meteor.isClient) {
        Meteor.subscribe('Adopcion');
    }
And now on `/server/publish.js`  you only make the publish function

```
//Publish methods
   Meteor.publish('Adopcion', function(){
          return Adopcion.find();
        });
```

With that there is no need of `Meteor.methods({})` and the first thing meteor will load its the collection, and they will be available on both client/server

Take a look and tell me if works for you

Comment: Thanks Etjana, you are right. I was not aware that gm was only available on the server. I'm just starting out so I don't yet know how to implement gm via the server. Will have to look into it. It's [methods](http://meteortips.com/book/methods/) I need to understand – right?

Comment: Check the update on the answer, and take try it, hope it works :D

Comment: Everything seems to work fine, no errors when starting. But then I get repeating errors:  

    GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=3lkaaq_h3u 503 (Service Unavailable)sockjs-0.3.4.js:854 AbstractXHRObject._startsockjs-0.3.4.js:888 (anonymous function)  

And the generated thumbnail is empty as well (zero kb)

Comment: and now it is crashing: Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> GraphicsMagick found
gm is available on the server
=> Meteor server restarted

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: check at the FSCollection declaration

Comment: Thanks again @Etjana. Unfortunately I'm still stuck. Can't get gm to work. :(

Comment: create an account on nitrous.io and lets make it work

Comment: Turns out Gif and Jpg files get converted. PNGs get corrupted though. I uploaded the app to GitHub https://github.com/c6y/eboydb Will check nitrous.io — Thanks @Etjana